# Looking for clarification on java.lang.System.load

Tags: java

I am trying to understand java.lang.System.load and why it can be a security problem. I have read a few blogs that say it can lead to Remote Code Execution, but they don't saw how or why. I think I am starting to put the pieces together, but would like some clarification.

Assuming the code below...

```
System.load("C:\path\to\evil.dll");
```

When something is loaded, does it cause the main method in evil.dll to run? for example if evil.java contained the method below, would it end up calling out to DoEvilThings()?

```
public static void main(string[] args) {
     DoEvilThings();
}
```

Assuming the answer to my question above is yes, is this problem limited to just java-based files or is it vulnerable files written in other languages?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the exact problem. Basically loading a file is exactly as safe as the file. If people can trigger `System.load` to execute on their arbitrary files, then they could as well send malicious code, so you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

Many libraries will not have a main method, so there is no requirement that its `main` method starts executing. See the example below from the [Java Native Interface Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jni/design.html#compiling-loading-and-linking-native-methods) which shows a library being invoked with no reference to a `main` function.

```
package pkg;

class Cls {
    native double f(int i, String s);
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("pkg_Cls");
    }
}
```

The problem is not limited to vulnerabilities in software written in Java. `System.load` and `System.loadLibrary` are part of the Java Native Interface Specification which, by definition, defines interoperability with other languages.

Comment: How is it determined which method runs? If the loaded file has 10 methods, will all 10 methods be called?

Comment: Which library method runs depends upon how the library is used after it is loaded.

Comment: To elaborate further, if the loaded file has 10 methods, all 10 methods will not immediately be called just from loading the library. Using my post and the 10 methods scenario as an example, once the function `f` is called from Java code (in my example it is only declared), native code begins execution, and could then invoke any other of the 9 remaining native methods.

Comment: So in my example, the main method won't be automatically called? The application doing the load would also need to know specifically call the main method?

Comment: My answer was in terms of whether main *had* to be called. The JNI specification mentions loading applications (which typically do have a main method) as well as libraries. The documentation for `System.load` also mentions differences in what will be invoked based upon whether or not the library is statically linked with the VM as well as implementation-dependent details. So I can't say exactly what would happen in your example.

Comment: Can you share the documentation link? My google-fu must be off today, because I keep getting junk results.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#load(java.lang.String)